# best practice for accessing authentication/authorization info from within model/ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have bought into the "thin controller, fat model" guideline.  That to me means that as little code as possible is in the controller, and most/all of the actual business logic is in the model (or in separate repository/services code).

In fact, I like the idea of the controller being a VERY simple conduit between the view and the model, and mostly concerned with calling an appropriate method in the model to do something, catch exceptions that then are added as ModelErrors, and deciding what view to go to next. Keep it as simple as possible.

At least I bought all this until I tried to write some code in my model that dealt with anything related to identity and roles.

It seems all the info required is in the Controller base class.  So the only way I can think of to really access that in a Model method is by passing it as parameters?  That gets really ugly really fast.

How can I access the info (IPrincipal, Session info etc) from within the Models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by creating a base Controller (and inheriting every controller from that) and a base Model (forcing each Model in my apps to inherit from that).

In the 2 base objects I've added 2 properties

```
public string UserId { get; private set; }
public Object UserInfo { get; private set; }
```

containing the readonly user informations (userId is also session stored, but for UserInfo I've used MemoryCache).

in this way I've got everything accessible from both my controllers and models ( even in Views obvioulsy).

Informations are setted just in the base controller (by overriding the OnAuthentication or using a custom AuthorizeAttribute).

I don't know if this is politically correct, but since I'm not bound to ASP.NET authoring (got to use SSO with Kerberos style), I've choose to implement in this way.

EDIT: How I do this:

I have an `HomeController` which simply stores userId in session then forwards to the real starting point of the webapp (a controller which extends my `BaseController`)

This pattern is secured by having the Authorize attribute on the base controller, each derived controller will have it applyed for each action, thus the OnAuthorization method of the base controller (or the one in your derived controller if you need to override for special cases) will be fired (e.g. No way to access without passing at least once from the HomeController/Index())

mock of the base controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HandleError]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)HttpContext.Session[MyConstants.UserId];
        }
    }
    public Object UserInfo
    {
        get { /* Access a MemoryCache with the UserId and SessionId */ }
    }


    [NonAction]
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        String Reason = "Everything's good :D";
        bool Ok = true;
        bool auth = true;
        // Base authorization (NTLM)
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        // Checks retriving UserId from session and base authentication
        Ok = ((UserId != null) && // Exits in session
              (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // is legit
         );
        if (!Ok) {
            Reason = "Meaningfull message (session expired or not authenticated)!";
        } else {
            // My Authorization Tests Start here
            try
            {
                MyUserInfo u = (MyUserInfo) UserInfo; 
                if (u != null) 
                {
                    // Found, check if has rights to access (heavy business logic in the IsAuthorized omitted)
                    Ok = u.IsAuthorized();
                }

                if (!Ok)
                {
                    Reason = "Your credentials don't allow you to do this!";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Reason = "doooh, exception checking auth: " + e.Message ;
                Ok = false;
            }
        }

        if (!Ok) {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                // If it was an ajax, I return a status 418, via global Ajax Error function I handle this
                // client side with an alert.
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResultWithJson(418, Reason); 
            }
            else
            {
                // Redirect to a specific Controller
                TempData["Reason"] = Reason;
                // A class which uses the Url helper in order to build up an url
                string denied = UrlFactory.GetUrl("Denied", "Errors", null);
                // Redirect
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(denied);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Of course you need an HomeController not inherithing from the base (the entry point of your webapp)

```
    public class HomeController : Controller 
    {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string StringaRandom, string HashCalcolato)
    {
        string Motivo = "";
        string UserId = null;
        try {
            bool UtenteCollegato = MySignOn(StringaRandom, HashCalcolato, ref UserId, ref  Motivo);
            // ok, valid user, SignOn stores UserInfos in a Cache (SLQ Server or MemoryCache)
            if (UtenteCollegato)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Session != null)
                {
                    // Salvo in sessione
                    HttpContext.Session.Add(MyConstants.UserId, UserId);
                }
                // Redirect to the start controller (which inherits from BaseController)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Start");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e);  
            Motivo = "Errore interno: " + e.Message;
        }
        HttpContext.Session.Remove(MyConstants.UserId);
        string denied = UrlFactory.GetUrl("Denied", "Errors", null);
        TempData["Reason"] = Motivo;
        return new RedirectResult(denied);
    }
  }
```

The StartController inherits from BaseController, thus each action needs OnAuthorize invocation before, since the StartController doesn't override it, the BaseController one is called.

More or less this is everything, as a bonus I add the HttpStatusCodeWithJon class.

```
public class HttpStatusCodeResultWithJson : JsonResult
{
    private int _statusCode;
    private string _description;
    public HttpStatusCodeResultWithJson(int statusCode, string description = null)
    {
        _statusCode = statusCode;
        _description = description;
    }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        response.StatusCode = _statusCode;
        response.StatusDescription = _description;
        base.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

this class is usefull to trigger STATUS errors for Ajax callbacks. If you use jQuery you can then use a global ajax error function to manage this.

This is it, maybe it's not elegant, maybe is not politically correct, but does almost everything I need, it's somewhat centralized, and for my current project works.

For models, simply add a public get, private set property for userid and userInfo and have them set in your model constructor (since each model is created in a controller you should have no problems at all on invoking the base model constructor via `: base(params)`

Warning: the code is a mock of the real thing (so can have typos or missing something), I've avoided to paste my business logic and reworked some parts, I guess it can be taken as a good hand drawn roadmap.

Let me know if this helps or if you need other infos.

PS:I was almost forgetting. Ff you work with ASP.NET profiles, Identities, I suggest you to look at the AuthorizeAttribute class, you can extend it and create your own Authorize Attribute, in that case, you don't need to write the OnAuthorization on the base controller or having inheritance (I still suggest you to have a base model and a base controller), but you'll provide that method in your Attribute. It's cleaner. I've not done it because of some legacy constraint with my Single Sign On solution, but will migrate to that.

Automatically Injection in the model can be done extending the ModelBinder (or registering a custom one). Never looked deep in that, I prefer another approach for data filtering (it's authorization not authentication, for me is app based and cannot rely on ASP.NET profiling)

The approach I would probably use is having a business object taking care of DataFiltering

Assume you've got an action like

```
ActionResult Something(SomeModel TheModel) {
  // perform anything
  TheModel.DoSomething();
  return View(TheModel);
}
```

you can change it to something like

```
ActionResult Something(SomeModel TheModel) 
{
   MyBusiness bsn = new MyNusiness(UserId, TheModel); // Give UserId or UserInfo directly to business
   TheModel = bsn.SomethingInABusinessWay();
   return View(TheModel);
}
```

or if you want to keep everything in your model, just add the UserId parameter to the DoSomething method. Yeah we're working with object, but there're cases in which an object can also rely on external data (not only on data members or properties).

This is a pretty neat and fast solution, major downside is adding a param to each vm business method, but it's better than scanning every single action in order to inject it (at least the compiler gives an error on each calls)

Will look further in injecting a sproperty in a model extending the default modelbinder as soon as I'll be free from some javascript namespaces nightmare I'm actually in. But if I recall correctly I've seen something like that on the net (Phil Haak or ScottGu's blogs or even here on SO), just search for Injecting data in a Model at runtime.

Comment: Hmmm  Interesting.  I'm still missing how you inject these properties into the Models from your base controller (where they are easily accessible via the MVC Controller base class) though. Few more details please?  Thank you...

Comment: WOW!  Thanks for taking the time to write all this out.  This is a very good roadmap.  
My issue is actually simpler though- you said that "For models, simply add a public get, ... via : base(params)".  This is where i am stuck.  Since methods in my controller take a ViewModel in as a parameter, I never have a chance to inject the userid etc into them.  I currently have to resort to doing a manual "push the userid info into vms"=> want to avoid this.  For those controller methods that create VMs, all is well.  Its those passed in VMs, built by the modelbinder that are the problems.

Comment: Well, the actions getting a VM as a parameter (as a result of posts or ajax) are in controllers, so they are "Authorized" (thus the OnAuthorization method of the base controller is actually executed). You can just add something like TempData[UserId] = UserId in the OnAuthorization Method and in that way you'll be sure you'll have the UserId (then use it to retrieve the UserInfos). But if you're using the User.Identity.Name stuff (from ASP.NET), I guess you can access that directly even in your VM default (parameterless constructor)

Comment: Yes, correct, actions getting a VM as a parameter are already authorized.  My reasons for needing things like username and role information are more related to filtering data based on access privs.  I am trying to use User.Identity.Name type things in my ViewModels, but there is no way to access a static User class right?  Since all of this is available in the controller base class, thats what started my search for how to (conventiently) inject that into my viewmodels, without resorting to manually pumping it in on most action methods.

Comment: I have tried injecting it in OnActionExecuting via filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model, but its always null.  The vms come in as parameters, but the viewdata.model is null?  I guess I can programmatically look around in the parameters collection for something that inherits from my ViewModelBase class, but that sounds uglier than the manual pump it in option :-)  Is the point simple, and I am just missing it?  Thank you so much for helping BigMike, it is appreciated!

Comment: My biggest surprise is that on a postback to the action method, filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model is always null (overriding OnActionExecuting to inject generically).  The strongly typed model is included as a parameter to the specific method, but the ViewData.Model is null.  So I cant figure out how to inject it in a generic manner.
Reading your edits does give me another avenue to check out - model binding, but Im kinda new at MVC, so it might be too advanced for me quite yet.  Ill report back if/when I have success with model binding.  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ALL YOUR TIME AND EFFORT!

Comment: The workaround I am currently using was your original suggestion (which I should have done as a matter of good practice).  I now have a ControllerBase and ViewModelBase that everything inherits from.  In VMB, I have these properties defined (userid, username etc).  Although I had wanted to inject these properties generically instead of having to do it manually in each action method (easy to forget to do it, DRY, etc), that is what I am doing.  I take the incoming model parameter on the action method, and blast the info into the model before making any model calls.  FYI

Comment: If you have a moment, could you take a look at this - its really short.  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775350/how-do-i-set-the-base-model-from-a-basecontroller-in-asp-net-mvc).  Im wondering if this could help me.  I think I can blast my user info into this base model, but Im a bit clueless about how to get my actual view models, that do inherit from that base class, to "use it as their base class instance".

Comment: Have you tried to inject into your model within a FilterAttribute ?AFAIK during the OnExecuting you've got full access to HttpContext (thus session). Don't inject into ViewData, inject directly into your model or TempData. That should work.